# Representations of product groups

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory

I would like to know (how to compute) the irreducible representations resulting from the decomposition of tensor-product representations of product groups.

For example:

Consider the group $SO_6\times SO_6$. Using a 2-tuple of Dynkin labels to denote representations of the product group, what is the decomposition (into irreps) of:
$\{(0\,a\,0),(0\,b\,0)\}\otimes\{(0\,c\,0),(0\,c\,0)\}$?

(I strongly expect that this is trivial (for the right persons); and so even a pointer to the right reference(s) would be appreciated!)

Comment: This is not trivial. Pretty much every textbook on the representation theory of lie groups will give you information about this, but it is in general messy (except for SL2, where you have the beautiful Clebsch-Gordan formula) The decomposition is algorithmic, and there are programs that will do it for you, like MAGMA.